# Do I need to submit for App Review for Facebook Graph API?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I use Graph API to publish video to Facebook, do I still need to do submission for App Review to Facebook?

I use this code:

```
  FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/videos", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID]
                                parameters:params
                                HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                        id result,
                                        NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Result uploaded video %@ %@", result, error);
    [spinner stopAnimating];

    UIAlertView *alert;
    if(error == nil){
      NSLog(@"not error");
      alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook"
                                         message:@"Video uploaded successfully"
                                        delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:nil
                               otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
      [alert show];
    }
    else{
      NSLog(@"error");
      alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook"
                                         message:error.description
                                        delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:nil
                               otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
      [alert show];
    }
  }];
```

It used to work some weeks ago, but suddenly now can't anymore. It says that vide publish is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`publish_actions`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-publish_actions) permission, which requires the App Review.

Comment: but why suddenly it doesn't work, while it worked in past?

Comment: @Rendy Either you were using a different user or an older API version, or it's a Facebook bug.

Comment: Nope.. During my development 2-3 weeks ago and on during UAT this early week still worked. While now isn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

App created with old versions still works. but after v2.3 facebook has updated the sdk and lot of things has changed. app created after v2.3 we need to submit app for review for publish actions.
     But in development mode we can create test users and with this test user we can publish posts on facebook. this test user wont be accessible with normal user.